# Horizontal Columns on SQL Report Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm creating a report in SSRS-2012, that have a table with some data, and must have two columns on each page.

I configured the page as A4 size, and configured the report, in report properties, to have 2 columns.
After that, I insert a tablix (only one) with some fields.

Here a screenshot of report design:
[image]

When I preview the report, the data appear on this order:

```
Table 1 | Table 3
Table 2 | Table 4
--- New Page ----
```

But I need that the report show something like this

```
Table 1 | Table 2
Table 3 | Table 4
--- New Page ----
```

- On green, how the report show data
- On red, how must show data
  [image]

How?
This is the first time I have used Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder

Sorry about the bad pictures!

Update: screenshots

Comment: If you have just placed 4 Tablix objects onto your report, why can you not just move them into the arrangement you desire?

Comment: I have add only 1 tablix! then, when I view the report, this data is iterated and show 4 tables (because 4 tables fit on the page) (updated my question)

Comment: Perhaps you could share a screenshot of your report design and the details of your underlying Dataset to help us understand the problem you're having? Personally I don't understand your text description referring to Table 1, 2, 3, 4, but then your statement that you only have one Table/Tablix - if your Dataset is returning 2 records (with two fields in each), then you need to address this from your Dataset to change how those values appear in a Tablix.

Comment: @3N1GM4, I have update my question, with some screenshots!

Comment: The multicolumn control is going to print top to bottom then left to right, in the order of the attached dataset. You would need to modify the order of the data returned by your dataset. Are the detail portions static in size? If so then you could apply a custom order to your data that would lay out the pages the way you want.

Comment: not a good solution! This is to much complicated, because the correct order depends of several fields. I then must create a "crazy" sql to generate a dataset that return objects in something like 'order by 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8...' :(

Comment: @Roberto Correia - If your page layout is static and you allow one page per whatever then It doesn't have to be overly complicated. If you group your data in a common way then all you have to do is apply a custom order within the group. If the groups will spill over on pagination, then yeah, you may have to come up with another idea.

Comment: tks @RossBush, I will try a different approach, maybe with some SQL modifications.

Comment: @Roberto Correia There are alternative ways to built this and not use the  "news letter style" supported by ssrs. Here is one link that might be useful --> http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/11/01/creating-multiple-column-reports/